# What are the things that only a large group of devs (like 30+) can make possible? Can a game still have the same quality with a small team?

Tags: teamwork

I just played Ori and found out the dev team was 25+ ppl(actually it was even more than that). I guess if it was just 5 people the game wouldnt last 15+ hours but is there anything else about the quality of the game that is only thanks to having like 25-30 devs? Or even 100+ devs for other games?
Thank you in advance for the answers! I really have no idea about game dev.

Comment: This depends a lot on the type of game. It would be hard to answer this in general for all conceivable games. If you want to develop a specific game of your own, and you need help scoping it to your available team and skills, or need help identifying what team and skills you'll need, try asking that more specific question instead: you'll get more useful, directly actionable answers.

Comment: go on fivver and see how fast freelancers can work, then assume professionals are around 10-15% faster.  then calculate based on what your game needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be possible to get you an idea of taking a look at a game that took a really large team and look at where all the work-hours went. Let's take Cyberpunk 2077, for example. [The credits](https://www.mobygames.com/game/128136/cyberpunk-2077/credits/windows/) list 3,169 (!) people. What did all these people do?

- Let's start with the actual main protagonist of the game: The city! It is huge. All the buildings are unique. Lots and lots of areas are created in painstaking detail. Every unique building, every type of object in the streets, every texture needs to be modeled and textured. Every area has *multiple* different lighting designs for different times of day. All of that was created manually, by humans.
- The story characters. The game features a ton of unique characters that appear in the story. Each of them needs an unique body and an unique face. Each of them needs unique clothes and accessories to be modeled. Each of them needs a voice actor to record their lines.
- The background characters. All those nameless pedestrians, bar patrons, car drivers and shopkeepers? And all those guards and gang members that are there just so you can shoot them? Someone needs to create those too. Yes, most of them are procedurally generated from a pool of character parts. But someone has to create all those character parts.
- The story cutscenes. Someone has to write them. Someone has to script the actions the NPCs perform during these cutscenes. Someone has to do the filmography of the cameras. And NPCs are going to perform actions during those scenes they don't perform during the actual game, so those actions need to be manually animated by someone. There are basically two ways to create game animations. You can hire another human actor to do motion capture and digitize it. Or you can hire another animator to manually position the characters joints. Quite often you do both: Use Mocap as a base and then have an animator correct the details.
- The vehicles. There are a hundred different cars and motorbikes in the game. Most of them with really detailed interiors and exteriors. Also a ton of work to model and texturize.
- Clothes. The game has a myriad of clothing option. Every piece of clothing must be modeled, textured and rigged for animation.
- Weapons and other gadgets. Everything the player-character can carry needs a detailed 3d model with unique animations.
- Mission design. Every mission has to be designed, tested and then redesigned several times. The redesign often requires to go back to the artists to create or change art assets. [Here is a presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXLRd5Kah-I) from the annual Game Developer Conference that goes into how much work goes into designing every single mission.
- Gameplay programming. A game like that has a ton of physics, mechanics, AI and other behaviors that require lots and lots of programming.
- Engine programming. The game has a custom rendering engine. Creating a rendering engine in this day and age is a ton of work too. Getting anything at all to show up on the screen is already a challenge for most programmers. But the engine of this game really does a lot. It ticks a lot of boxes when it comes to utilizing the bleeding edge of rendering technology. And all that while being able to work with a huge and detailed world that can be traversed without visible borders or loading screens. Keeping that all in memory is impossible, so it needs to be capable of loading and unloading geometry in real-time. This is really advanced stuff that requires a lot of programmer hours to get working.
- Music. The game has 11 **hours** of soundtrack with 177 different tracks across several musical genres. Some music might be licensed, but most of it was created specifically for the game. All that music doesn't compose, arrange and master itself.
- ...and I could go on with lots and lots of other things.

**tl;dr:** Making games is a lot of hard work from a lot of professionals with all kinds of different areas of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

There is no valid answer to the question you're asking.

You would have to define what a dev does. Are we talking exclusively about *programmers*? Or those 30 devs are actually programmers, artists, designers, testers, IT staff, managers, accountants, marketing and the person answering calls and welcoming visitors at the front desk? If they're only *programmers*, we need to assume there are other folks working on that game, and the size of the rest of the team may vary a lot based on the type of game developed (as it's been mentioned in the comments).

And then you need to take into consideration what those devs *are*, what kind of experience do they have? The velocity of a team composed of experience devs where the communication, team spirit and goal is good will likely be much different compared to the velocity of a team of folks fresh out of school where everyone wants to pull the design in their own direction and where some key process are just unknown to them.

Then you need to consider how deep the studio's pockets are, which will influence how long the team has to produce the game.